Is there a way to count the items in a list in one cell on Google Sheets?
image here
I would like it to be able to type in lists of names in one cell, as pictured, and have a count of how many names there are in the cell next to it.
I am not familiar with coding beyond the very basics so not sure how to do this. Thanks :)
